# astropy fits how many extentions?

Tags: python, astropy

Is there a way to see how many extensions your fits file has? So if my file looks like this for example, how can I get 309 back without opening every frame and blowing up my ram?

```
Filename: a.fits
No.    Name         Type      Cards   Dimensions   Format
0    PRIMARY     PrimaryHDU     828   ()              
1    CHIP1.HCYCLE11  ImageHDU        52   (1024, 900)   float32   
2    CHIP1.HCYCLE21  ImageHDU        52   (1024, 900)   float32   
3    CHIP1.HCYCLE12  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
4    CHIP1.HCYCLE22  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
5    CHIP1.HCYCLE13  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
6    CHIP1.HCYCLE23  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
7    CHIP1.HCYCLE14  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
8    CHIP1.HCYCLE24  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
9    CHIP1.HCYCLE15  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
10   CHIP1.HCYCLE25  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
11   CHIP1.HCYCLE16  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
12   CHIP1.HCYCLE26  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
13   CHIP1.HCYCLE17  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
14   CHIP1.HCYCLE27  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
15   CHIP1.HCYCLE18  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
16   CHIP1.HCYCLE28  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
17   CHIP1.HCYCLE19  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
18   CHIP1.HCYCLE29  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
19   CHIP1.HCYCLE110  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
20   CHIP1.HCYCLE210  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
21   CHIP1.HCYCLE111  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
22   CHIP1.HCYCLE211  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
23   CHIP1.HCYCLE112  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
24   CHIP1.HCYCLE212  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
25   CHIP1.HCYCLE113  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
26   CHIP1.HCYCLE213  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
27   CHIP1.HCYCLE114  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
28   CHIP1.HCYCLE214  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
29   CHIP1.HCYCLE115  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
30   CHIP1.HCYCLE215  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
31   CHIP1.HCYCLE116  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
32   CHIP1.HCYCLE216  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
33   CHIP1.HCYCLE117  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
34   CHIP1.HCYCLE217  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
35   CHIP1.HCYCLE118  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
36   CHIP1.HCYCLE218  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
37   CHIP1.HCYCLE119  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
38   CHIP1.HCYCLE219  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
39   CHIP1.HCYCLE120  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
40   CHIP1.HCYCLE220  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
41   CHIP1.HCYCLE121  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
42   CHIP1.HCYCLE221  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
43   CHIP1.HCYCLE122  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
44   CHIP1.HCYCLE222  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
45   CHIP1.HCYCLE123  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
46   CHIP1.HCYCLE223  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
47   CHIP1.HCYCLE124  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
48   CHIP1.HCYCLE224  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
49   CHIP1.HCYCLE125  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
50   CHIP1.HCYCLE225  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
51   CHIP1.HCYCLE126  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
52   CHIP1.HCYCLE226  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
53   CHIP1.HCYCLE127  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
54   CHIP1.HCYCLE227  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
55   CHIP1.HCYCLE128  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
56   CHIP1.HCYCLE228  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
57   CHIP1.HCYCLE129  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
58   CHIP1.HCYCLE229  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
59   CHIP1.HCYCLE130  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
60   CHIP1.HCYCLE230  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
61   CHIP1.HCYCLE131  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
62   CHIP1.HCYCLE231  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
63   CHIP1.HCYCLE132  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
64   CHIP1.HCYCLE232  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
65   CHIP1.HCYCLE133  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
66   CHIP1.HCYCLE233  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
67   CHIP1.HCYCLE134  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
68   CHIP1.HCYCLE234  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
69   CHIP1.HCYCLE135  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
70   CHIP1.HCYCLE235  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
71   CHIP1.HCYCLE136  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
72   CHIP1.HCYCLE236  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
73   CHIP1.HCYCLE137  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
74   CHIP1.HCYCLE237  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
75   CHIP1.HCYCLE138  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
76   CHIP1.HCYCLE238  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
77   CHIP1.HCYCLE139  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
78   CHIP1.HCYCLE239  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
79   CHIP1.HCYCLE140  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
80   CHIP1.HCYCLE240  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
81   CHIP1.HCYCLE141  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
82   CHIP1.HCYCLE241  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
83   CHIP1.HCYCLE142  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
84   CHIP1.HCYCLE242  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
85   CHIP1.HCYCLE143  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
86   CHIP1.HCYCLE243  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
87   CHIP1.HCYCLE144  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
88   CHIP1.HCYCLE244  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
89   CHIP1.HCYCLE145  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
90   CHIP1.HCYCLE245  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
91   CHIP1.HCYCLE146  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
92   CHIP1.HCYCLE246  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
93   CHIP1.HCYCLE147  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
94   CHIP1.HCYCLE247  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
95   CHIP1.HCYCLE148  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
96   CHIP1.HCYCLE248  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
97   CHIP1.HCYCLE149  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
98   CHIP1.HCYCLE249  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
99   CHIP1.HCYCLE150  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
100  CHIP1.HCYCLE250  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
101  CHIP1.HCYCLE151  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
102  CHIP1.HCYCLE251  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
103  CHIP1.HCYCLE152  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
104  CHIP1.HCYCLE252  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
105  CHIP1.HCYCLE153  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
106  CHIP1.HCYCLE253  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
107  CHIP1.HCYCLE154  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
108  CHIP1.HCYCLE254  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
109  CHIP1.HCYCLE155  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
110  CHIP1.HCYCLE255  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
111  CHIP1.HCYCLE156  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
112  CHIP1.HCYCLE256  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
113  CHIP1.HCYCLE157  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
114  CHIP1.HCYCLE257  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
115  CHIP1.HCYCLE158  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
116  CHIP1.HCYCLE258  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
117  CHIP1.HCYCLE159  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
118  CHIP1.HCYCLE259  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
119  CHIP1.HCYCLE160  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
120  CHIP1.HCYCLE260  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
121  CHIP1.HCYCLE161  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
122  CHIP1.HCYCLE261  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
123  CHIP1.HCYCLE162  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
124  CHIP1.HCYCLE262  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
125  CHIP1.HCYCLE163  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
126  CHIP1.HCYCLE263  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
127  CHIP1.HCYCLE164  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
128  CHIP1.HCYCLE264  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
129  CHIP1.HCYCLE165  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
130  CHIP1.HCYCLE265  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
131  CHIP1.HCYCLE166  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
132  CHIP1.HCYCLE266  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
133  CHIP1.HCYCLE167  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
134  CHIP1.HCYCLE267  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
135  CHIP1.HCYCLE168  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
136  CHIP1.HCYCLE268  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
137  CHIP1.HCYCLE169  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
138  CHIP1.HCYCLE269  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
139  CHIP1.HCYCLE170  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
140  CHIP1.HCYCLE270  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
141  CHIP1.HCYCLE171  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
142  CHIP1.HCYCLE271  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
143  CHIP1.HCYCLE172  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
144  CHIP1.HCYCLE272  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
145  CHIP1.HCYCLE173  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
146  CHIP1.HCYCLE273  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
147  CHIP1.HCYCLE174  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
148  CHIP1.HCYCLE274  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
149  CHIP1.HCYCLE175  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
150  CHIP1.HCYCLE275  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
151  CHIP1.HCYCLE176  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
152  CHIP1.HCYCLE276  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
153  CHIP1.HCYCLE177  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
154  CHIP1.HCYCLE277  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
155  CHIP1.HCYCLE178  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
156  CHIP1.HCYCLE278  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
157  CHIP1.HCYCLE179  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
158  CHIP1.HCYCLE279  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
159  CHIP1.HCYCLE180  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
160  CHIP1.HCYCLE280  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
161  CHIP1.HCYCLE181  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
162  CHIP1.HCYCLE281  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
163  CHIP1.HCYCLE182  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
164  CHIP1.HCYCLE282  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
165  CHIP1.HCYCLE183  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
166  CHIP1.HCYCLE283  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
167  CHIP1.HCYCLE184  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
168  CHIP1.HCYCLE284  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
169  CHIP1.HCYCLE185  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
170  CHIP1.HCYCLE285  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
171  CHIP1.HCYCLE186  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
172  CHIP1.HCYCLE286  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
173  CHIP1.HCYCLE187  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
174  CHIP1.HCYCLE287  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
175  CHIP1.HCYCLE188  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
176  CHIP1.HCYCLE288  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
177  CHIP1.HCYCLE189  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
178  CHIP1.HCYCLE289  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
179  CHIP1.HCYCLE190  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
180  CHIP1.HCYCLE290  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
181  CHIP1.HCYCLE191  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
182  CHIP1.HCYCLE291  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
183  CHIP1.HCYCLE192  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
184  CHIP1.HCYCLE292  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
185  CHIP1.HCYCLE193  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
186  CHIP1.HCYCLE293  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
187  CHIP1.HCYCLE194  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
188  CHIP1.HCYCLE294  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
189  CHIP1.HCYCLE195  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
190  CHIP1.HCYCLE295  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
191  CHIP1.HCYCLE196  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
192  CHIP1.HCYCLE296  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
193  CHIP1.HCYCLE197  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
194  CHIP1.HCYCLE297  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
195  CHIP1.HCYCLE198  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
196  CHIP1.HCYCLE298  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
197  CHIP1.HCYCLE199  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
198  CHIP1.HCYCLE299  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
199  CHIP1.HCYCLE1100  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
200  CHIP1.HCYCLE2100  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
201  CHIP1.HCYCLE1101  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
202  CHIP1.HCYCLE2101  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
203  CHIP1.HCYCLE1102  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
204  CHIP1.HCYCLE2102  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
205  CHIP1.HCYCLE1103  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
206  CHIP1.HCYCLE2103  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
207  CHIP1.HCYCLE1104  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
208  CHIP1.HCYCLE2104  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
209  CHIP1.HCYCLE1105  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
210  CHIP1.HCYCLE2105  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
211  CHIP1.HCYCLE1106  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
212  CHIP1.HCYCLE2106  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
213  CHIP1.HCYCLE1107  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
214  CHIP1.HCYCLE2107  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
215  CHIP1.HCYCLE1108  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
216  CHIP1.HCYCLE2108  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
217  CHIP1.HCYCLE1109  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
218  CHIP1.HCYCLE2109  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
219  CHIP1.HCYCLE1110  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
220  CHIP1.HCYCLE2110  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
221  CHIP1.HCYCLE1111  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
222  CHIP1.HCYCLE2111  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
223  CHIP1.HCYCLE1112  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
224  CHIP1.HCYCLE2112  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
225  CHIP1.HCYCLE1113  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
226  CHIP1.HCYCLE2113  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
227  CHIP1.HCYCLE1114  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
228  CHIP1.HCYCLE2114  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
229  CHIP1.HCYCLE1115  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
230  CHIP1.HCYCLE2115  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
231  CHIP1.HCYCLE1116  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
232  CHIP1.HCYCLE2116  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
233  CHIP1.HCYCLE1117  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
234  CHIP1.HCYCLE2117  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
235  CHIP1.HCYCLE1118  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
236  CHIP1.HCYCLE2118  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
237  CHIP1.HCYCLE1119  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
238  CHIP1.HCYCLE2119  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
239  CHIP1.HCYCLE1120  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
240  CHIP1.HCYCLE2120  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
241  CHIP1.HCYCLE1121  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
242  CHIP1.HCYCLE2121  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
243  CHIP1.HCYCLE1122  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
244  CHIP1.HCYCLE2122  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
245  CHIP1.HCYCLE1123  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
246  CHIP1.HCYCLE2123  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
247  CHIP1.HCYCLE1124  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
248  CHIP1.HCYCLE2124  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
249  CHIP1.HCYCLE1125  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
250  CHIP1.HCYCLE2125  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
251  CHIP1.HCYCLE1126  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
252  CHIP1.HCYCLE2126  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
253  CHIP1.HCYCLE1127  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
254  CHIP1.HCYCLE2127  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
255  CHIP1.HCYCLE1128  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
256  CHIP1.HCYCLE2128  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
257  CHIP1.HCYCLE1129  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
258  CHIP1.HCYCLE2129  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
259  CHIP1.HCYCLE1130  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
260  CHIP1.HCYCLE2130  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
261  CHIP1.HCYCLE1131  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
262  CHIP1.HCYCLE2131  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
263  CHIP1.HCYCLE1132  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
264  CHIP1.HCYCLE2132  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
265  CHIP1.HCYCLE1133  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
266  CHIP1.HCYCLE2133  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
267  CHIP1.HCYCLE1134  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
268  CHIP1.HCYCLE2134  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
269  CHIP1.HCYCLE1135  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
270  CHIP1.HCYCLE2135  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
271  CHIP1.HCYCLE1136  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
272  CHIP1.HCYCLE2136  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
273  CHIP1.HCYCLE1137  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
274  CHIP1.HCYCLE2137  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
275  CHIP1.HCYCLE1138  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
276  CHIP1.HCYCLE2138  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
277  CHIP1.HCYCLE1139  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
278  CHIP1.HCYCLE2139  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
279  CHIP1.HCYCLE1140  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
280  CHIP1.HCYCLE2140  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
281  CHIP1.HCYCLE1141  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
282  CHIP1.HCYCLE2141  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
283  CHIP1.HCYCLE1142  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
284  CHIP1.HCYCLE2142  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
285  CHIP1.HCYCLE1143  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
286  CHIP1.HCYCLE2143  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
287  CHIP1.HCYCLE1144  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
288  CHIP1.HCYCLE2144  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
289  CHIP1.HCYCLE1145  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
290  CHIP1.HCYCLE2145  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
291  CHIP1.HCYCLE1146  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
292  CHIP1.HCYCLE2146  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
293  CHIP1.HCYCLE1147  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
294  CHIP1.HCYCLE2147  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
295  CHIP1.HCYCLE1148  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
296  CHIP1.HCYCLE2148  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
297  CHIP1.HCYCLE1149  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
298  CHIP1.HCYCLE2149  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
299  CHIP1.HCYCLE1150  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
300  CHIP1.HCYCLE2150  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
301  CHIP1.HCYCLE1151  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
302  CHIP1.HCYCLE2151  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
303  CHIP1.HCYCLE1152  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
304  CHIP1.HCYCLE2152  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
305  CHIP1.HCYCLE1153  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
306  CHIP1.HCYCLE2153  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
307  CHIP1.HCYCLE1154  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
308  CHIP1.HCYCLE2154  ImageHDU        50   (1024, 900)   float32   
309  CHIP1.INT1  ImageHDU        52   (1024, 900)   float32
```

Answer (score 3):

How are you currently opening your file? `astropy.io.fits.open(...)` will open the file *without* blowing up your RAM, and return a `HDUList`, which is, as the name implies, a list of `HDU`s (extensions). Getting the length of that list gives you the number of extensions (including the first/primary header):

```
len(astropy.io.fits.open(...))
```

---

If you have a tool like [`ag`](http://geoff.greer.fm/ag/) installed, you could use something like:

```
ag  -c 'END\s{77}'  ./Downloads/bayestar.fits
```

since each HDU will have a header that requires the `END` keyword, and padding to a multiple of 80 (2880, to be precise). 
Note that this won't work with `grep`, but `ag` and [`ack`](http://beyondgrep.com) both work.